# Why my python got a different result from VScode to Colab?

Tags: python, numpy, visual-studio-code

I want to calculate matrix using computer, but when I run these code on VScode it shows the weird result, but on colab it's completely correct.

```
import numpy as np

A = [[4, 6, 2],
     [3, 4, 1],
     [2, 8, 13]]

s = [9, 7, 2]

r = np.linalg.solve(A, s)

print(r)


>>>> [ 3.00000000e+00 -5.00000000e-01 -1.98254112e-17] # VScode (The interpret is python 3.8.8 anaconda ) 

>>>> [ 3.  -0.5  0. ] #Colab
```

I think it's might be wrong with my anaconda, so I update it but nothing changes.

Does anyone know how can I to fix it ? Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The values are equivalent This is just floating-point precision. Colab may be rounding it automatically as part of its frontend config - if you round the vscode values to 1 decimal, you will get the colab results.